# Docusign Responsive Signing Input field alters flow

Tags: docusignapi

I have a document (docx file) to be signed. This form has two signature fields and one phone number input fields. Customers can sign this from a web application or from a mobile application (xamarin forms app)
When I enabled responsive signing, I found a typical issue with respect to the phone number entry field.

I have tried this will all 3 possible signing navigation modes and they all result in below behavior.
Using the next button the user can sign and the form does not ask for text input.
After both sign is completed, user is asked to press next button
On clicking next the user is taken to another page where the same form is loaded but responsive layout and the toggle are off
And user is keying in the phone number.

The phone number field is being treated as mandatory that is why unless you type you cannot proceed to complete the signing.

However if you use the toggle button to make it responsive its actually not seen and that probably is the reason why its not shown while user is actually signing.

This makes me wonder if the responsive view is recognizing the phone number text field as a responsive field

I want to know how can we make sure the phone number is entered while signing?

As I said my form is in a docx file and I am reading the content. I am adding signatures as below.

```
private InPersonSigner CreateInPersonSigner(

            string documentId,
            int recipientId,
            string clientId,
            string role,
            string name,
            string anchorTag, string email, string phoneAnchor)
        {
            InPersonSigner signer = new InPersonSigner();
            signer.ClientUserId = clientId;
            signer.RecipientId = recipientId.ToString();
            signer.Name = name;
            signer.SignerName = name;
            signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
            signer.RoleName = role;
            signer.HostEmail = email;
            signer.HostName = AppConstants.AppConstants.HostName;
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
            SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
            signHere.DocumentId = documentId;
            signHere.AnchorHorizontalAlignment = AppConstants.AppConstants.AnchorHorizontalAlignment;
            signHere.Name = AppConstants.AppConstants.SignerTagName;
            signHere.AnchorString = anchorTag;
            signer.Tabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
            signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);
            **if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneAnchor))
            {
                signer.Tabs.TextTabs.Add(CreatePhoneAnchor(documentId, phoneAnchor));**
            }
            return signer;
        }

private Text CreatePhoneAnchor(string documentId, string phoneAnchor)
        {
            var phoneText = new Text
            {
                DocumentId = documentId,
                Name = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.Name,
                AnchorString = phoneAnchor,
                MaxLength = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.MaxLength,
                Width = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.Width,
                Height = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.Height,

                DisableAutoSize = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.DisableAutoSize,
                TabLabel = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.TabLabel,
                Tooltip = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.Tooltip,
                ValidationPattern = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.ValidationPattern,
                ValidationMessage = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.ValidationMessage,
                FontColor = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.FontColor,
                Required = AppConstants.AppConstants.PhoneAnchor.Required
            };
            return phoneText;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about you calling this "responsive signing". That term in DocuSign means you send HTML and the tabs are in the HTML. You are sending in a docx and define the tabs yourself. So what do you mean by responsive? viewing it on mobile? is that what you mean? same envelope works ok in desktop browser, but not ok on mobile device?

Comment: I think terminologies were not right. I mean mobile friendly view. However I got the issue resolved. There was a bad style applied on the anchor tag in the word doc which was failing to render in the mobile friendly view which when corrected started working.

Comment: However I do have some UI related issues (Sorry I am bring in another issue from the original ticket). The phone number entry field is way off the place. added a screen shot. Docusign is using some divs which are adding the space. Is this normal or is there a way to remove the spacings.

Comment: you can "anchorXOffset": "10", "anchorYOffset": "-10"
These values move the textbox in this case from its position to where you need it. You can experiment until you get the right numbers and it looks good

Answer (score 1):

When using anchor tags, you can move the tags in relative to where the anchor strings were found on the document.

Use the **AnchorXOffset** and **AnchorYOffset** parameters in the **SignHere** or **Text** (Tab) object do set the number of points (or pixels) that your tab should be in relation to where the string was found (note these can be negative numbers as well).

Trying and seeing how these tabs move is the best way to position your tabs perfectly.